# How exactly one can show parametric equations in a graph

Tags: analytic-geometry

I'm trying to understand parametric equations, it looks simple but it tricks me.

$x = 3-2t\\y=1+t\\z=2+3t$

How do I plot it ? I mean, where's $t$ in the graph?

Comment: Think of it as a point which moves around in time. If you took all of it's positions and ploted them you would get a curve, which would be a way of viewing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you view $t$ as a parameter you don't plot it.  If you just had the first two equations, you would have a straight line in $\Bbb R^2$.  With the third equation you have a straight line in $\Bbb R^3$.  You can plot that, but need to do it in perspective and it may not show up well.  This would be a line through $(3,1,2)$ in the direction of $(-2,1,3)$

Comment: And if I have only $y=2x+2$ how do I know the direction of $x$ is $1$?

Comment: If you have only $y=2x+2$ it is not a parametric equation.  It is a straight line with slope $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Parametric equations are usually used to plot curves in the plane (or, in this case, three-dimensional space) with some parameter. Here, $t$ is that parameter, and is used to trace out the curve (this is actually a line in which $(3, 1, 2)$ lies on the line and moves in the direction of the vector $(-2, 1, 3)$. You would still plot this in $\mathbb{R}^3$ noting that movement depends on $t$.

Comment: When t= 0, x= 3−2(0)= 3, y= 1+ 0= 1, and z= 2+ 3(0)= 2.  That's where Ross Milliken and the others got the point (3, 1, 2).  When t= 1, x= 3- 2(1)= 1, y= 1+ 1= 2, and z= 2+ 3(1)= 5.  That's where they got the other point (1, 2, 5).   The fact that every one of these parametric equations is linear tells us that the graph is a straight line.   Two points determine a line.  
y=1+t
z=2+3t

Answer (score 1):

You can ask Wolfram Alpha to "plot parametric curve (3-2t, 1+t, 2-3t) for -10<=t<=10" [[link]](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20parametric%20curve%20(3-2t,%201%2Bt,%202-3t)%20for%20-10%3C%3Dt%3C%3D10). (The graph is a straight line that goes from corner to corner of a box in the output, so it's not all that enlightening to look at for understanding parametric equations.)

Answer (score 0):

Um here you would indeed have to plot it in $\Bbb R^4$ to fully plot it. But you could also eliminate the $t$ to get an equation involving $x,y,z$. Then you can eliminate another. Also as another answer suggests when plotting a parameterized curve you do not typically plot the parameters.

But on to parameterized curve. Another way to say is $$l(t)=\langle 3-2t, 1+t, 2+3t \rangle$$

Or $$=\langle -2,1,3 \rangle t + \langle 3,1,2 \rangle$$

$$=(3-2t)\mathbf x+(1+t)\mathbf y + (2+3t)\mathbf z$$

Or the image of the map $$\{(x,y,z) \in \Bbb R^3 \ : \ y=\frac{x-1}{2} \cap y=\frac{z+1}{3}\}$$ which is what you want to plot. To be technical if you said you want to plot the **graph** then that would be in $\Bbb R^4$.

Another way to think of it is that the curve starts at $(3,1,2)$ and has constant velocity $$\frac{d}{dt}l(t)=\mathbf v=\langle -2,1,3 \rangle$$ and the plot you want is the projection unto $\Bbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

Normally when we make such a parameterization we do not plot $t$. We simply vary $t$ and determine the point $(X(t),~ Y(t),~ Z(t))$. A circle is a circle, but a rational parameterization of the circle gives us a way to find rational points directly, which is rather non-trivial given the full quadratic.